# lions/lioness hunt as a pack or as a pride

Tags: word-usage

I know that a group of lions is called a pride.
In the context of hunting, should I say "they hunt as a pack" or "they hunt as a pride"?
Which one is the right usage ?

Answer (score 1):

The more common expressions are ***“hunt in pride/s”, “hunt in pack/s”.***

From [The Hunt](https://books.google.it/books?id=o-W7CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22hunt%20in%20prides%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDyrWh_fHlAhXJwAIHHTdcDcAQ6AEIJzAA) - Page 25 Alastair Fothergill, ‎Huw Cordey - 2015 - ‎

> So why do most of the Serengeti's ***lionesses still hunt in prides?*** There seem to be two key reasons.

From: [Gir  Forest and the Saga of the Asiatic Lion](https://books.google.it/books?id=J0rME6RjC1sC&pg=PA120&dq=%22hunt%20in%20prides%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDyrWh_fHlAhXJwAIHHTdcDcAQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22hunt%20in%20prides%22&f=false) - Page 120
Sudipta Mitra - 2005

> Unlike in Africa, the Asiatic ***lions do not hunt in pride*** and often stalk the prey individually. In Africa, the lions are adapted ***to hunt in prides*** where...

From [howitworksdaily.com:](https://www.howitworksdaily.com/why-do-lions-hunt-in-packs-but-tigers-alone/)

> Why do ***lions hunt in packs*** but tigers alone?

Answer (score 0):

the second one sounds a little silly, but [many of these words](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/word-lists/list-of-names-for-groups-of-animals.html) referring to sets of animals are–and many intentionally so... depending on your audience, you could use either one, although someone may ask you to justify which word you use. there's no right or wrong answer, a pride, a group, a pack, although yes, pack is usually used with wolves and dogs, not cats.

so, you could go with *pride* and be technically correct and have a resource to justify your choice of word, or go with something more generic as *group* and have horse sense to back you up. I guess I would stay away from *pack* of lions, as the dogs/wolves have a corner on that word.

Comment: Few people bother with the correct collective noun beyond the obvious.